# Using function-scoped variable in a tidyverse filter expression

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have this code:

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(df, var) {
  message("var is ", var)
  df %>% filter(var==var)
}

df <- data.frame(var=c(1,2,3))
foo(df, 3)
```

The output is unfiltered, because `var==var` uses only the data frame column, and not the function parameter.  See below:

```
> foo(df, 3)
var is 3
  var
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

What I always do is rename the function parameter `the_var`, and use `var == the_var`.  However, I'd like to learn more about tidyverse scoping.

How can I filter the `var` column by the `var` function parameter value without changing any names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can escape the variable inside the function to check the variable outside the environment of the data

```
foo <- function(df, var) {
  message("var is ", var)
   df %>% 
       filter(var == !!var)
 }
```

-output

```
foo(df, 3)
#var is 3
#  var
#1   3
```